# How to send json data using inetc::post in the nsis

Tags: nsis

I am using NSIS script for Rest API to send HTTP post with the JSON message body but unfortunately, I didn't find any solution.
Using of query string I can implement but I need to HTTP post request with JSON  or as a raw message body.

inetc::post "" "sampleurl.php?username=$arg1&password=$arg2" "C:\output.txt" /END
With this query string we can request http post but I need HTTP post request with JSON or a raw message body.
I tried below command to send data to the sample url but $0 got "url parts error"

inetc::post ""{\"a\": \"a1\",\"b\": \"" + $username + "\",\"c\": \"" + $password + "\",\"d\": \"" + Windows + "\"}"" "http://sampleURL" "C:\output.log" /END

pop $4
MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP "perfect install $4"

```
 inetc::post "" "sampleurl.php?username=$arg1&password=$arg2" "C:\output.log" /END
```

I expect output to request an HTTP post call with JSON or raw message body using nsis

Comment: Is the server not receiving any POST data or is the data wrong somehow?

Comment: Today I have tried below command here we got an error as "Request Error(415)" Here just hard coded all the values


      inetc::post "$\"{$\"a$\": $\"a1$\", $\"b$\": $\"username$\", $\"c$\": $\"password$\", $\"d$\": $\"Windows$\"}$\"" "sampleurl" "C:\output.log" /END

Comment: inetc::post /HEADER "Content-Type: application/json"  "$\"{$\"a$\": $\"a1$\", $\"b$\": $\"username$\", $\"c$\": $\"password$\", $\"d$\": $\"Windows$\"}$\"" "sampleurl" "C:\output.log" /END

With this command also got "Request Error(415)"

Comment: It looks like you are quoting too much of the JSON parameter, try `"{$\"a$\":666,$\"b$\":42}"`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
With the above comment also it is not working. I have verified below arguments as per your suggestion:
inetc::post /HEADER "Content-Type: application/json" "{$\"a$\": $\"a1$\", $\"b$\": $\"username$\", $\"c$\": $\"password$\", $\"d$\": $\"Windows$\"}" "sampleurl" "C:\output.log" /END

Why content-type is not taking as json data after giving header as application/json?
Is nsis will support json data in the inetc::post call?

Comment: First of all, inetc is a 3rd-party plug-in, it is not part of NSIS. Second, I don't see how inetc is the problem but I don't have a server I can test with so I can't really help.